# How to enable/disable token transfer?

Tags: erc-20

I'm trying to modify an ERC20 token.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

// ================= Ownable Contract start =============================
/*
 * Ownable
 *
 * Base contract with an owner.
 * Provides onlyOwner modifier, which prevents function from running if it is called by anyone other than the owner.
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }
}
// ================= Ownable Contract end ===============================

// ================= Safemath Contract start ============================
/* taking ideas from FirstBlood token */
contract SafeMath {

  function safeAdd(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal returns(uint256) {
    uint256 z = x + y;
    assert((z >= x) && (z >= y));
    return z;
  }

  function safeSubtract(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal returns(uint256) {
    assert(x >= y);
    uint256 z = x - y;
    return z;
  }

  function safeMult(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal returns(uint256) {
    uint256 z = x * y;
    assert((x == 0)||(z/x == y));
    return z;
  }
}
// ================= Safemath Contract end ==============================

// ================= ERC20 Token Contract start =========================
/*
 * ERC20 interface
 * see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 {
  uint public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint);
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint);

  function transfer(address to, uint value) returns (bool ok);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) returns (bool ok);
  function approve(address spender, uint value) returns (bool ok);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}
// ================= ERC20 Token Contract end ===========================

// ================= Standard Token Contract start ======================
contract StandardToken is ERC20, SafeMath {

  /**
  * @dev Fix for the ERC20 short address attack.
   */
  modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint size) {
    require(msg.data.length >= size + 4) ;
    _;
  }

  mapping(address => uint) balances;
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) allowed;

  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32)  returns (bool success){
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSubtract(balances[msg.sender], _value);
    balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) returns (bool success) {
    var _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
    balances[_from] = safeSubtract(balances[_from], _value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = safeSubtract(_allowance, _value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }
}
// ================= Standard Token Contract end ========================

// ================= Pausable Token Contract start ======================
/**
 * @title Pausable
 * @dev Base contract which allows children to implement an emergency stop mechanism.
 */
contract Pausable is Ownable {
  event Pause();
  event Unpause();

  bool public paused = false;


  /**
  * @dev modifier to allow actions only when the contract IS paused
  */
  modifier whenNotPaused() {
    require (!paused);
    _;
  }

  /**
  * @dev modifier to allow actions only when the contract IS NOT paused
  */
  modifier whenPaused {
    require (paused) ;
    _;
  }

  /**
  * @dev called by the owner to pause, triggers stopped state
  */
  function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
    paused = true;
    Pause();
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev called by the owner to unpause, returns to normal state
  */
  function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused returns (bool) {
    paused = false;
    Unpause();
    return true;
  }
}
// ================= Pausable Token Contract end ========================

// ================= IcoToken  start =======================
contract IcoToken is SafeMath, StandardToken, Pausable {
  string public name;
  string public symbol;
  uint256 public decimals;
  string public version;
  address public icoContract;

  function IcoToken(
    string _name,
    string _symbol,
    uint256 _decimals,
    string _version
  )
  {
    name = _name;
    symbol = _symbol;
    decimals = _decimals;
    version = _version;
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
    return super.transfer(_to,_value);
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint _value) whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
    return super.approve(_spender,_value);
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance) {
    return super.balanceOf(_owner);
  }

  function setIcoContract(address _icoContract) onlyOwner {
    if (_icoContract != address(0)) {
      icoContract = _icoContract;
    }
  }

  function sell(address _recipient, uint256 _value) whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
      assert(_value > 0);
      require(msg.sender == icoContract);

      balances[_recipient] += _value;
      totalSupply += _value;

      Transfer(0x0, owner, _value);
      Transfer(owner, _recipient, _value);
      return true;
  }

}

// ================= Ico Token Contract end =======================

// ================= Actual Sale Contract Start ====================
contract IcoContract is SafeMath, Pausable {
  IcoToken public ico;

  uint256 public tokenCreationCap;
  uint256 public totalSupply;

  address public ethFundDeposit;
  address public icoAddress;

  uint256 public fundingStartTime;
  uint256 public fundingEndTime;
  uint256 public minContribution;

  bool public isFinalized;
  uint256 public tokenExchangeRate;

  event LogCreateICO(address from, address to, uint256 val);

  function CreateICO(address to, uint256 val) internal returns (bool success) {
    LogCreateICO(0x0, to, val);
    return ico.sell(to, val);
  }

  function IcoContract(
    address _ethFundDeposit,
    address _icoAddress,
    uint256 _tokenCreationCap,
    uint256 _tokenExchangeRate,
    uint256 _fundingStartTime,
    uint256 _fundingEndTime,
    uint256 _minContribution
  )
  {
    ethFundDeposit = _ethFundDeposit;
    icoAddress = _icoAddress;
    tokenCreationCap = _tokenCreationCap;
    tokenExchangeRate = _tokenExchangeRate;
    fundingStartTime = _fundingStartTime;
    minContribution = _minContribution;
    fundingEndTime = _fundingEndTime;
    ico = IcoToken(icoAddress);
    isFinalized = false;
  }

  function () payable {    
    createTokens(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }

  /// @dev Accepts ether and creates new ICO tokens.
  function createTokens(address _beneficiary, uint256 _value) internal whenNotPaused {
    require (tokenCreationCap > totalSupply);
    require (now >= fundingStartTime);
    require (now <= fundingEndTime);
    require (_value >= minContribution);
    require (!isFinalized);

    uint256 tokens = safeMult(_value, tokenExchangeRate);
    uint256 checkedSupply = safeAdd(totalSupply, tokens);

    if (tokenCreationCap < checkedSupply) {        
      uint256 tokensToAllocate = safeSubtract(tokenCreationCap, totalSupply);
      uint256 tokensToRefund   = safeSubtract(tokens, tokensToAllocate);
      totalSupply = tokenCreationCap;
      uint256 etherToRefund = tokensToRefund / tokenExchangeRate;

      require(CreateICO(_beneficiary, tokensToAllocate));
      msg.sender.transfer(etherToRefund);
      ethFundDeposit.transfer(this.balance);
      return;
    }

    totalSupply = checkedSupply;

    require(CreateICO(_beneficiary, tokens)); 
    ethFundDeposit.transfer(this.balance);
  }

  /// @dev Ends the funding period and sends the ETH home
  function finalize() external onlyOwner {
    require (!isFinalized);
    // move to operational
    isFinalized = true;
    ethFundDeposit.transfer(this.balance);
  }
}
```

Would anyone guide me how to get total tokens has been sold and total ETH has been received?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract IcoToken inherits Pausable so you can just call the function pause() to stop any activity among token holders.
Total tokens sold are held in the totalSupply variable of the ICO contract: it's public so you can simply read it without cresting a function.
Total eth received is kept in the ICO contract so you just have to check its balance, again without writing any function to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Marco Ottolini. I would like to have separate function to start transfer tokens between users. Would you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a separate function to "control" transfers between users. The function transfer() in the IcoToken contract is already doing its job: it allows user A to send tokens to user B, but only if you haven't stopped the IcoToken contract to do so, calling the function pause(). What other functionality do you need?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Marco Ottolini. I have found the solution for myself ^^